# Match all from the Regexp till it reachs a certain string PHP

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = 'href="http://grego.com" href="httpxoobar" href="xxx" href="ZZZZZ"';

preg_match_all('/http:\/\/(?<!href=")([\s\S]+)"/', $str,$m);


print_r($m);
```

I'm trying this code.

I want to create 4 matches, I want to match all the    href="  that doesn't have "http://" after it, and then get what is inside the href="(this)" (I'm using \s\S because it may contain new lines) and when it finds a quote ( " ) it stops and keep fetching the next (that in this case is in the same line),

in this example it should bring all 4 results.

how do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you mean?? http://www.rubular.com/r/hkmteeWWBZ (I added a newline on purpose to the second href to test that case)

Comment: Hi Mellamokb, thanks for answering, well what you did is still matching href="http://grego.com" , I need to NOT match them, Only match href="azauhz" href="whatever", hrefs that don't have http:// after the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got things a bit mixed up.

- You've made `http://` part of the match although you're writing that you *don't*  want to match it,
- you're using a negative lookbehind where a positive one would make sense,
- you're not using the `/s` option to allow the dot to match newlines,
- you're using a greedy quantifier that will match too much, and
- you're using regexes to match HTML.

That said, you might get away with this:

```
(?<=href=")(?!http://)[^"]+
```

i. e. in PHP:

```
preg_match_all(
    '%(?<=href=") # Assert position right after href="
    (?!http://)   # Assert that http:// is not right ahead
    [^"]+         # Match one or more characters until the next "
    %x', 
    $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, it works. I have one question though, what is the difference between using the delimiter % or / in the beginning? I never saw anything but the / as the delimiter. thanks again ^^

Comment: You can choose nearly any non-alphanumeric character as a delimiter (or paired ones like `<>`), which makes sense if the regex contains slashes. Otherwise, you'd have to escape them (`http:\/\/`).